# How to skip wrapping to Try if the argument is already a Try-instance?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a method which wraps a block to `Try`:

`def wrapToTry[T](arg: =>T):Try[T] = Try(arg)`

Then what if `arg` passed is already an instance of `Try[U]`? I would like the wrapping method in this case just return the `arg` itself without wrapping. So far the only way I've come up with to do this is following:

`def wrapToTry[T,U](arg: =>T):Try[U] = if(arg.isInstanceOf[Try[U]]) arg.asInstanceOf[Try[U]] else Try(arg).asInstanceOf[Try[U]]`

I really don't like it and tried to figure out how to solve it. 
First I tried to overload:

```
def wrapToTry[T](arg: =>T):Try[T] = Try(arg)

def wrapToTry[T](arg: =>Try[T]):Try[T] = arg
```

but that does not compile due to type erasure with the compilation error

```
Error:(10, 7) double definition:
def wrapToTry[T](arg: => T): scala.util.Try[T] at line 8 and
def wrapToTry[T](arg: => scala.util.Try[T]): scala.util.Try[T] at line 10
have same type after erasure: (arg: Function0)scala.util.Try
  def wrapToTry[T](arg: =>Try[T]):Try[T] = arg
      ^
```

Ok, I got it, this is because the parameter is by-name, lesson learned. 
Then my idea was to create an overloaded version of the method with evidence like in the following snippet:

```
object Test {
  import scala.util.Try
  import scala.util.Success

  def wrapToTry[T](arg: =>T):Try[T] = Try(arg)

  def wrapToTry[T, U](arg: =>T)(implicit evidence: T <:< Try[U]) = arg

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    println(wrapToTry("alex"))
    println(wrapToTry(Success("alex")))
  }

}
```

But that does not compile due to ambiguity with the following compiler error:

```
Error:(15, 13) ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method wrapToTry in object Test of type [T, U](arg: => T)(implicit evidence: <:<[T,scala.util.Try[U]])T
and  method wrapToTry in object Test of type [T](arg: => T)scala.util.Try[T]
match argument types (String) and expected result type Any
    println(wrapToTry("alex"))
            ^
```

I do believe there should be an elegant way to implement this. Could you advice?

***************************************UPDATE*************************************

Per request of readers who think the problem in this question is useless here goes the context in which the problem arises.

TLDR

I have an DSL to simplify work with ScalaTest suites.
Part of this DSL implementation is:

```
class Test(block: => Assertion){

    def afterThat[T, U](followUp: =>T):Assertion = {
      val start = Try(block)
      val followUpAttempt:Try[U] = if(followUp.isInstanceOf[Try[U]]) followUp.asInstanceOf[Try[U]] else Try(followUp.asInstanceOf[U])
      start.flatMap(r => followUpAttempt.map(_ => r)).get
    }

  }

  object Test{
    def apply(body: => Assertion):Test = new Test(body)
    implicit def assertionToTest(a: => Assertion):Test = new Test(a)
  }
```

This allows me to write tests like the following one:

```
"Admin" should "be able to create a new interest segment" in{
    val group = interestsGroup
    val segment = tempInterestSegment
    Test{
      Given("an existing interests segment group")
      SegmentGroupsPage.open
      SegmentGroupsPage.createNewSegmentGroup(group)
      And("admin is on Segments view")
      SegmentsPage.open
      When("he creates a new interest segment in this segment group")
      SegmentsPage.createNewSegment(segment)
      Then("this segment is shown in the list")
      SegmentsPage.isParticularSegmentShownInTheList(segment.name) shouldBe true
      And("it has correct values on its details view.")
      SegmentsPage.openSegmentDetailsView(segment.name)
      SegmentsPage.fieldsHaveCorrectValues(segment) shouldBe true
    } afterThat cleanUpTest(segment, group)
  }
```

Also I can have as many `afterThat` at the end of each test as I want to. Each of them gets wrapped into `Try` so I am sure they ALL get executed and in the end I still have my original `Assertion` as a result.

Then I encountered a test where a follow-up block which I pass to `afterThat` is already a `Try` instance. It will work BUT I SIMPLY DONT LIKE NESTED TRY so decided to exercise if I will be able to solve this.

Comment: The thing is, if you _know_ at compile time that the argument is a `Try`, you simply do not need to "wrap" it. And if you don't know that, the the compiler has no way of knowing that either. So, whatever trick you come up with to implement this, it seems like it would be pretty useless.

Comment: Dima, precisely, I don't know in advance if the `arg` will be` Try` or something else. So I want a polymorphic method. If the `arg` was by-value - then I would be able to simply provide an overloaded version of the method and that's all. But I need it to be by-name and that complicates.
Regarding uselessness - I simplified here the model for the question to remove all the unneeded details, but the original problem appeared in a more complex real life domain, I just can't paste here pages of code since no one will ever bother to read that.

Comment: What I am saying is you don't need to wrap something, that's is already wrapped. And if you don't know if it is wrapped or not, then the compiler has no way of knowing it either. FWIW, your last solution works if you write it like `wrapToTry[String]("alex")`

Comment: It might be nice if you added it to the question ... very hard to read it here :/

Comment: Dima, I have added a context for you. Hope it is more clear now why I have started to think over such problem.

Comment: Your intention is to make sure that if there is a failed `Try` somewhere, its exception will always be thrown?

Comment: Jasper-M: precisely. Even if the test body works out fine but one of follow-ups produces some error - I want to fail the test with that exception. Follow-ups are usually different cleanups which are needed.

Comment: If this is the same as your previous question where you're working with Async tests, then you should just work with Futures for lazy eval, since all results are Futures in async tests.

Comment: som-snytt: I work with Futures where there's really asynchronous stuff, for example when I need to query Slick. But not sure if this is a good idea to wrap everything in Future where there is no need for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard solution for such overloading is

```
def wrapToTry[T](arg: =>T):Try[T] = Try(arg)

def wrapToTry[T](arg: =>Try[T])(implicit d: DummyImplicit):Try[T] = arg
```

Note there is a caveat: the second version will only be called if `arg` is known to by a `Try` at compile-time. E.g.

```
def foo(arg: Any) = wrapToTry(arg)

foo(Try(1))
```

will produce `Success(Success(1))`. But this will likely be shared by all reasonable solutions (I am not counting your initial version as reasonable).

Comment: Alexey, could you explain why exactly it works?
I've checked it really works, did not know there is such a thing as 'DummyImplicit' in Predef.scala.
I am trying to get a bit better than a monkey, so want to learn why this works :)

Comment: is it just because the second method gets an additional arguments list, so its signature is different now and definitions are no longer identical?

Comment: @AlexanderArendar It's just because the erased types of the methods are now different: `(arg: Function0)Try` vs `(arg: Function0, d: DummyImplicit)Try`.

Comment: I see. Reading about type erasure now as well.

Comment: Wow, `DummyImplicit` thingy is pretty cool! :) I didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 5):

I would go with specialised implicits here:

```
object Helpers {
  implicit class TryConverter[T](obj: => T) {
    def asTry: Try[T] = Try(obj)
  }

  implicit class TryIdentity[T](obj: => Try[T]) {
    def asTry: Try[T] = obj
  }
}
```

Now the compiler can do its type magic for you.

```
import Helpers._
```

And then call `.asTry` anywhere you need to. You should not intermediate this with something that returns `Any` though, why lose type specialisation  voluntarily?

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it doesn't compile. It should be (val obj:  T) I think

Comment: @C4stor Correct, I typed without double checking, `val` parameters cannot be call by name. I've updated.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on having 1 method name for both Try and non-Try arguments, which is understandable in case of a DSL, you can use a typeclass based trick. One variation of which you can see here:

```
class Test(block: => Assertion){

  def afterThat[T](followUp: =>T)(implicit after: Test.AfterThat[T]): Assertion = 
    after(block, followUp)

}

object Test {
  def apply(body: => Assertion): Test = new Test(body)
  implicit def assertionToTest(a: => Assertion): Test = new Test(a)

  private[Test] sealed trait AfterThat[T] {
    def apply(block: => Assertion, f: => T): Assertion
  }

  private[Test] object AfterThat extends LowerPriority {
    implicit def itsaTry[T,U](implicit ev: T <:< Try[U]) = new AfterThat[T] {
      def apply(block: => Assertion, f: => T): Assertion = {
        val start = Try(block)
        val followUp = ev(f)
        start.flatMap(r => followUp.map(_ => r)).get
      }
    }
  }

  private[Test] trait LowerPriority {
    implicit def notTry[T] = new AfterThat[T] {
      def apply(block: => Assertion, f: => T): Assertion = {
        implicitly[AfterThat[Try[T]]].apply(block, Try(f))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Jasmper-M: thanks, I need some time to crunch through this, not so easy for me yet.